# Control validation annotations order?

Tags: operator-precedence, hibernate-validator

A field has two validation annotations

```java
@NotEmpty
@Length(min=3,max=100)
String firstName;
```

#### Observation

If that field is left empty, then the resulting violations vary in order:

- sometimes the `@NotEmpty` is violated first
- other times the `@Length` is violated first

#### Questions

How does *Hibernate* specify the order in which validations (annotations) are processed?
Can this validation order be customized?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very questionable observation regarding bean-validation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use JSR-303 validation groups.

If no groups are specified a constraint is part of the Default Bean Validation group (see: `javax.validation.groups.Default`).

Create an interface to be your "Extended" (or whatever you want to call it) group:

```
public interface Extended{}
```

Now create an interface that will have the `javax.validation.GroupSequence` annotation.

```
@GroupSequence({Default.class, Extended.class})
public interface MySequence {}
```

Set the validation groups on your constraints

```
@NotEmpty // If no group is specified it is part of the default group
@Length(min=3,max=100, groups = Extended.class)
String firstName;
```

Pass MySequence to your validator call.

```
validator.validate(object, MySequence.class);
```

As specified by your `@GroupSequence` the default constraints will be validated first and if no contraint violations are encountered it will move on to the extended group.

Comment: i am using @valid annotation, any other ideas ?

Comment: I'm afraid I think you will have to wait for https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6373 to be resolved (or call the validator yourself). Have look at this article as well: http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2010/12/28/spring-mvc-and-jsr-303-validation-groups/

Comment: @MahmoudS You can setup a CDI decorator to handle this task, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325520/hibernate-error-with-custom-bean-validation

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the above answer, the group sequence could also be done at the Class level where validations have been defined.
For example:

Provided we have two interfaces

```
public interface FirstOrder{}
public interface SecondOrder{}
```

We could define them as a group sequence as below

```
@GroupSequence({MyTestClass.class,FirstOrder.class,SecondOrder.class})
public class MyTestClass{

@NotBlank(groups = FirstOrder.class)    
@Length(min=3, max=100, groups = SecondOrder.class)
private String name; 

}
```

Advantage of doing the group sequence this way is -

You do not need an extra interface to define the group sequence and as a result you do not need to pass that to the validator for your unit/IT tests.

Comment: Works perfectly.