# Hibernate Error with Custom Bean Validation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I'm trying to create a custom bean validation, so I write this custom constraint:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidPackageSizeValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidPackageSize {

  String message() default "{br.com.barracuda.constraints.ValidPackageSize}";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

And a validator:

```
public class ValidPackageSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPackageSize, PackageSize> {

...

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(PackageSize value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    ...validation login here..
  }

}
```

Also, I wanted the validation to be performed on the service layer just after some decorators are called, so I created an another decorator to handle this task..

```
@Decorator
public abstract class ConstraintsViolationHandlerDecorator<T extends AbstractBaseEntity> implements CrudService<T> {

  @Any
  @Inject
  @Delegate
  CrudService<T> delegate;

  @Inject
  Validator validator;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public T save(T entity) {
      triggerValidations(entity);
      return delegate.save(entity);
  }

  private void triggerValidations(T entity) {
      List<String> errorMessages = validator.validate(entity).stream()
            .map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
      if (!errorMessages.isEmpty()) {
        throw new AppConstraintViolationException(errorMessages);
      }
  }
}
```

Everything works, but if validations pass, hibernate throws an error:

```
ERROR [default task-6] (AssertionFailure.java:50) - HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in br.com.barracuda.model.entities.impl.PackageSize entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

My entities use auto-generated `id` values.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id;
```

Using Widlfly 9 with JEE 7.

Answer (score 1):

Validation was being executed twice, once in the service layer (where I wanted it to happen) and once when entity was persisted/merged (jpa was calling it). So I disabled it by adding this line to my `persistence.xml`:

`<property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>`

Now everything works fine