# Hibernate validator sequence or order

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am working with **hibernate framework** and I want to apply **hibernate constraint** on my **@Entity** class. I want to execute/run constraint on it's order/sequence as define inside @Entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User{
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]+")
    @Length(max = 10)
    private String firstName;
}
```

I want to execute constrain as below order:

```
    1) @NotNull
    2) @NotBlank
    3) @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]+")
    4) @Length(max = 10)
```

Any one please help me how can I achieve it. I also want to apply constrain order/sequence on more than one field.

Comment: Currently its not executing in this order?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571231/control-validation-annotations-order

Answer (score 0):

There are Group and GroupSequence concepts in Hibernate validations. Check them. 
If I apply those concepts your code will look like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@GroupSequence({One.class, Two.class, Three.class, Four.class})
public class User{
    @NotNull(groups={One.class})
    @NotBlank(groups={One.class})
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]+" ,groups={One.class})
    @Length(max = 10,groups={One.class})
    private String firstName;
}
```